# if do not care commit history, merge and rebase the same in git?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

If I just need to integrate my change with other changes (no matter if other changes are related to my change or not), and I do not quite care about commit history, I think merge and rebase serve the same purpose? In other words, git pull and git refetch+git rebase serve the same purpose?

Comment: Yes, in the context of `pull`.

Comment: @1615903 Rebasing will maintain a linear history, while merging will introduce merge commits everywhere.  But functionally, both do serve the same purpose in terms of keeping your branch up to date with the remote.

Comment: @1615903, what do you mean yes, the same to me?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks, it seems if I do not care history, they are the same, correct?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen _"both do serve the same purpose in terms of keeping your branch up to date with the remote"_ - that was the question as far as I understood it.

Comment: If you just want to bring your local branch up to date, then doing `git pull` and `git pull --rebase` will seem to have the same effect.  In practice, they're not doing the same thing, but since you told us that doesn't matter, then choose one and use it (I recommend `git pull` for this purpose).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, when I execute `git pull` does it pull to my local master branch (suppose I work on local master branch), or it pull to my local `origin/master` branch?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: `git pull` is equivalent to doing `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.  Fetch updates `origin/master` and merge then merges this into your local branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks, so you mean `git fetch` step of `git pull` is to keep `origin/master` up to date with remote master? And `git merge` step of `git pull` is to merge local branch `origin/master` with local branch `master`?

Comment: Affirmative ...

Comment: @1615903, thanks, so after study, does it mean git fetch step of git pull is to keep origin/master up to date with remote master? And git merge step of git pull is to merge local branch origin/master with local branch master?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks, why not add a reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit other people, your description is more clear than git official document. :)

Comment: There are so many Stack Overflow question extant which already discuss this.  I wouldn't want to duplicate myself out!  But I'm glad you've sorted out your doubts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124958/discussion-between-lin-ma-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, you rock!

Comment: I don't, but check out [this profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) if you want to see a real Git legend.

Comment: Rebase will create copies of your commits with new IDs. The content of your files might be the same, but the repository will be very different